# How to categorize product by it's types in Asp.net using Webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, dropdown, vs-web-site-project

**I want to sort the products by their type, using dropdownlist.**

products by types isn't working when i select it in dropdown list.

[image]

stored procedure of ProductByType:

```
Public List<Product> GetProductsByType(int typeId)
    {
        try
        {
            using (GarageDBEntities db = new GarageDBEntities())
            {
                //select * from table where condition is required type
                List<Product> products = (from x in db.Products
                                          where x.TypeId == typeId
                                          select x).ToList();
                return products;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Index page code to display products:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillPage();
    }

    private void FillPage()
    {
        //Get a lsit of all products in DB
        ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
        List<Product> products = productModel.GetAllProducts();

        //Make sure products exists in the database
        if (products != null)
        {
            //Create a new Panel with an ImageButton and 2 labels for each Product
            foreach (Product product in products)
            {
                Panel productPanel = new Panel();
                ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
                Label lblName = new Label();
                Label lblPrice = new Label();

                //Set childControls properties
                imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Products/" + product.Image;
                imageButton.CssClass = "productImage";
                imageButton.PostBackUrl = "~/Pages/Product.aspx?id=" + product.Id;

                lblName.Text = product.Name;
                lblName.CssClass = "productName";

                lblPrice.Text = "₹" + product.Price;
                lblPrice.CssClass = "productPrice";

                //Add child controls to Panel
                productPanel.Controls.Add(imageButton);
                productPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
                productPanel.Controls.Add(lblName);
                productPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
                productPanel.Controls.Add(lblPrice);

                //Add dynamic Panels to static Parent panel
                pnlProducts.Controls.Add(productPanel);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //No products found
            pnlProducts.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "No Products Found!" });
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
        List<Product> products = productModel.GetProductsByType(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value));

            foreach (Product product in products)
            {
                Panel productPanel = new Panel();
                ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
                Label lblName = new Label();
                Label lblPrice = new Label();

                //Set childControls properties
                imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Products/" + product.Image;
                imageButton.CssClass = "productImage";
                imageButton.PostBackUrl = "~/Pages/Product.aspx?id=" + product.Id;

                lblName.Text = product.Name;
                lblName.CssClass = "productName";

                lblPrice.Text = "₹" + product.Price;
                lblPrice.CssClass = "productPrice";

                //Add child controls to Panel
                productPanel.Controls.Add(imageButton);
                productPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
                productPanel.Controls.Add(lblName);
                productPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
                productPanel.Controls.Add(lblPrice);

                //Add dynamic Panels to static Parent panel
                pnlProducts.Controls.Add(productPanel);
            }
    }
}
```

It always showing all the products even tho when I select product type.
As shown in image, I selected "Engine Oil" but it showing all the products.
I want it to show particular products only of the selected product type chosen in dropdownlist.

Comment: That catch block isn't doing you any favors. At the very least, *log* that you got an error! Don't just discard it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add the `PostBack` validation in your `Page_Load` event:

**C# Code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillPage();
    }
}
```

Most likely, when selecting an item in the dropdownlist, a postback is generated which will call `PageLoad` and reload all the products, to avoid this the PostBack validation is usually set

Make sure to use the `AutoPostBack="True"` flag in the `<asp:DropDownList />` control

Comment: Thank you @Julián for your reply. It worked.
I was bothered from last 3 days and you solved it. I appreciate it.